What is the true history of the blue bricks of Old San Juan?
During a recent visit to Old San Juan, Puerto Rico, I was told that the distinctive blue bricks on its streets (see here) were cast from steel byproducts, served as ballast in Spanish ships, and were nearly indestructible, among other things.  At one point, I was also shown an illustration of a Puerto Rican governor (see here) and told that the view behind him showed enslaved people paving a street with the aforementioned blue bricks.
I did a little research to try to confirm these claims, and "Scoria bricks" seem to have the same appearance of what was used (see here).  That said, these weren't developed until the 1870s--just a few decades before Puerto Rico became a US territory and about 80 years after the governor pictured above (Miguel Antonio de Ustariz) had left office.  I don't know much about naval history, but I also question whether vessels from this era would have used something like these bricks for ballast.
In summary, what is the true history of the "blue streets"?  Where were the bricks manufactured?  Were they truly cast from molten slag, or were they manufactured from some other process?  When were the streets paved with the current bricks?  And were they ever used as ship ballast?

Hmm... Interesting question. Doing some research, I read that (natural) cobblestones (from Europe) came in spanish ships as ballast (common when there was no trade but only a one-way-loaded trip). Then (later), when needed, some were replaced, possibly (probably?) by scoria bricks. That would not just explain the painting though :/

Here is a hi-res version of the portrait that you can zoom in on.

If these bricks were used as ballast in Spanish ships then presumably they should also appear in any port frequented by Spanish ships of that period.

There does seem to be a combination of myth and history concerning these blue slag cobblestones or adoquines as they are known in Spanish.  The actual History surrounding these objects appears to be quite complex, but I have found some sources which agree on certain aspects relating the story of these interesting bricks.
So far the Myth aspect is often repeated, especially among tourist and travel guide type sites, but without any supporting documentation that I have been able to find. This relates the early arrival of these slag bricks as ballast on Spanish ships, at a time early enough that the streets were paved utilizing slaves as the labor force. The portrait the OP points out places this as during the time of governor Brigadier General Miguel Antonio de Ustáriz, who served from July 8, 1789 until May 19, 1792. This shows the streets being paved with blue cobblestone, and being installed by slave labor. The legend is intact. The only issue is there is no evidence that slag bricks arrived in Puerto Rico before the 19th century. I have located one source which provides a viable alternative.
A book, Ancestors and Descendents of Dr Bernardo de Urrutia Matos Vol Two
By Francisco José Ginorio Viscal, When discussing the achievements of a different, earlier in fact, governor, Field Marshal Don Juan Andrés Daban y Busterino who served from   April 6, 1783 until March 27, 1789. has the following entry:

Ordered the paving of the streets of San Juan - using the hard granite
quarried in the Canary Islands and used as ballast on merchant ships,
Governor Daban ordered the reuse of this granite as paving bricks for
San Juan.

This seems to fit the confusing narrative much better, time is right, material is loaded as ballast, its just not the expected iron slag bricks, which didn't seem to fit in that timeline.
When did the iron slag bricks actually arrive and replace the granite then? Several sources agree on late 19th century as the time when the well known
adoquines made their appearance on the scene.
Another book about San Juan, The Architecture of San Juan de Puerto Rico: Five centuries of urban and architectural experimentation, By Arleen Pabon-Charneco, mentions a visitor to San Juan in the early 1890s excited at the prospect of some upcoming urban renewal (emphasis mine):

"On the whole, the town of San Juan may be considered one of the best
in the West Indies; and when the streets shall be newly paved and
flagged, as is projected, it will be rendered still more neat and
agreeable."

This correlates with another source, Matters of Inscription: Reading Figures of Latinidad  by Christina A. León, which has an article investigating the importance of the term adoquines within San Juan based literature or poetry:

The fabled adoquines, or cobblestones, of Old San Juan share the
color of the ocean-an iridescent, opulent blue that shimmers across
the old colonial streets of San Juan. Most assume that the adoquines
of Old San Juan came to the island as ballast from Spanish colonial
ships, but the bricks came from England during a set of years before
the island's relationship to the English language itself would shift
radically, between 1890 and 1896.

The same author goes on with more details concerning these British bricks:

The adoquines of Old San Juan were an early infrastructure project,
with roads first being paved with wood, then granite blocks called
chinos, and finally the adoquines that concern this coda. While many
assume that these stones were once ballast from Spanish ships, in
actuality, they were ordered from Huntly Brothers in Sunderland,
England. A report entitled "Los adoquines de escoria en San Juan," or
"San Juan's cobblestones of waste," shows an even stranger provenance...

So this paragraph provides agreement with the earlier generation of granite pavers, and even provides a source concerning the procurement of the well known slag bricks.
At this point most of the issues should be cleared up. The first genration of paving stones were granite, procured from ballast used by Spanish merchants travelling from the Canary Island in the 1700s. A later renewel project ordered the famous blue scoria bricks in the late 19th century.
One more twist however.
An online article in Contigent magazine, The Colony of Cobblestone
has some information concerning the eventual fate of these cobblestones:

These blue cobblestones also played a role in the relationship between
Puerto Rico and the United States.2 During the Cold War, the U.S.
sought to modernize Puerto Rico’s economy, as a bulwark against the
spreading influence of communism in the Caribbean and Latin America.
Part of this project was developing the island’s tourism industry,
with Old San Juan at the forefront. Plans to renovate Old San Juan,
which at that time was a slum with many abandoned and derelict
buildings, were proposed in 1951; construction began in 1955 under a
government project called Operation Serenity...


Renovating Old San Juan meant placing new cobblestones throughout the
city. These cobblestones were supposed to add to Old San Juan’s
European-style aesthetic. But the images of worn cobblestones are
nonetheless illusions, conjured as a result of U.S. rule. The
cobblestones were made to look old despite being new.

So in the end the myth has indeed replaced the reality...

Wow! Thank you for this tremendously well-researched answer. I had no idea where to start on my search for more information about this subject, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

This was one of those answers I had to write just to be able to close half the browser tabs  I had left open when I found something relevant.

I'm confused. I looked at the high-res image of the governor with the slaves paving the road, and nothing in that image suggests to me that what the slaves are laying are "blue" in any way. I mean they COULD be, but it seems equally possible they are regular bricks. Possibly even granite like the other part of the story says.
